# SwiftUIでObservedObjectなオブジェクトでメインスレッドで実行するよう設定するSwiftUIらしい書き方が知りたい

Tags: swift, swiftui

下記コードの `self.message = "OK"` と  `self.message = "NG"` のところで以下のエラーが発生します。

```
Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Network

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message = ""
    
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "network_monitor")
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                self.message = "OK"
            } else {
                self.message = "NG"
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentViewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(self.contentViewModel.message)
        }.frame(
            maxWidth: .infinity,
            maxHeight: .infinity
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

警告を回避し、メインスレッドで動かすのであれば

```
if path.status == .satisfied {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.message = "OK"
    }
} else {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.message = "NG"
    }
}
```

と `DispatchQueue.main.async` で囲めば解決しますが、警告には `via operators like receive(on:)` といってるので `receive(on:)` を使う書き方があるのでしょうか？　そしてそれはどのように書くのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 警告には `via operators like receive(on:)` といってるので `receive(on:)` を使う書き方があるのでしょうか？

警告の文言は、「バックグラウンドスレッドからの`@Published`変数の更新」一般について出されるものなので、特に`NWPathMonitor`のようなクラスを意識したものではなく、「`URLSession.dataTask`のように`Publisher`が得られる代替APIが存在する場合」を念頭に置いたものだろうと思われます。

特に「`Publisher`が得られる代替API」が存在しない場合に、無理に`receive(on:)`を使う必要はないのではないでしょうか。

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message = ""
    
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                self.message = "OK"
            } else {
                self.message = "NG"
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: .main) //<- ここで`DispatchQueue.main`を使う
    }
}
```

---

無理にでも`receive(on:)`を使うような形に書くと、こんな風になるでしょう。

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message = ""
    
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "network_monitor")
    
    private let subject = PassthroughSubject<NWPath, Never>()
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            self.subject.send(path)
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
        cancellable = subject.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink {path in
                if path.status == .satisfied {
                    self.message = "OK"
                } else {
                    self.message = "NG"
                }
            }
    }
}
```

[NWPathMonitor を Combine の Publisher として扱えるようにする拡張](https://gist.github.com/YusukeHosonuma/0a39266dd5c2232d6d0a42f826adb8e6)なんてものも見つかりましたが、Networkフレームワークに公式にCombine系のAPIが追加されない限り、今回のような処理では大きなメリットは無いように思われます。

Comment: なるほど。`(queue: .main)`としちゃってよいのでしょうか？ これだと `pathUpdateHandler` 内を mainで実行してくれるかもしれないですが、ネットワークのチェック自体も main で行われたりしないでしょうか？
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor/2998737-start
それとも pathUpdateHandler のところだけに関する queue の設定なのでしょうか？　マニュアルを見たけど確信が持てませんでした。

Comment: @shingo.nakanishi さん、相変わらずNetworkフレームワークのドキュメントはスカスカですね。こちらとしては、実際に観測できる動きから推定せざるを得ないと言うところです。「`.main`を指定してもpathの更新は検出できている」「更新の通知が確実にメインスレッドで実行されている」と言ったことから、問題ないと判断しています。

Comment: なるほど。ドキュメントからは厳密にはわからないので、状況判断していること理解しました。